# Simple 2 columns layout

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I would like to have a webpage with two columns. The first for buttons, and the second for content.

Here's a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VT9m3/6/) :

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="home">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <div class="home-header">
        <div class="content-header" data-tap-toggle="false">
            Header
        </div>
    </div>  
</div> 
<div data-role="content">
    <div>
        <div class="ActionsMenu">       
            <button>button</button>
            <button>button</button>
            <button>button</button>
            <button>button</button>
        </div>

        <div id="ActionsContent">
            <h3 class="ui-bar ui-bar-a ui-corner-all">Heading</h3>
      <div class="ui-body">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse accumsan blandit fermentum. Pellentesque cursus mauris purus, auctor commodo mi ullamcorper nec. Donec semper mattis eros, nec condimentum ante sollicitudin quis. Etiam orci sem, porttitor ut tellus nec, blandit posuere urna. Proin a arcu non lacus pretium faucibus. Aliquam sed est porttitor, ullamcorper urna nec, vehicula lorem. Cras porttitor est lorem, non venenatis diam convallis congue.</p>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    footer
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ActionsMenu {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
.ActionsContent {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}

@media all and (min-width: 400px) {
    .ActionsMenu {
      float: left;
      width: 25%;
      padding-right: 50px;

    }
    .ActionsContent {
      float: none;
      margin-left: 25%;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the content is under the buttons and not where I need it...

The page also need to be responsive and display a single column for mobiles...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VT9m3/7/)

Have width prpperty defined for both the divs.

As you are going for responsive design i suggest using % widths

```
.MainContent .ActionsMenu {
    width: 25%;
    float: none;
    overflow-scrolling: auto;
}
.MainContent .ActionsContent {
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
}
```

Have float element to float the content right

And You should have a id ActionsMenu in HTML not class.

```
<div class="ActionsMenu"> ..</div>
```

EDIT:
You want to align to right-http://jsfiddle.net/VT9m3/11/ add padding based on that

```
.ActionsContent {
      float: left;
        width:65%;
    padding-left:20px;
    }
```

but as your padding on the same div might break at a resoultion if the width of `.ActionsMenu+.Actionscontent+padding >100%` so have the Action menu in another div and have width property to it then have .ActionContent and have the padding

Comment: Thanks! What if I don't want the content to be aligned to the right, but to the left instead with only a space between the buttons and the content ?

Comment: It is preferred to use another div with padding inside the floated div in order to avoid design break. This is better instead of applying padding and float to same div.

Comment: You want to align to right-http://jsfiddle.net/VT9m3/11/ add padding based on that   .ActionsContent {
      float: left;
        width:65%;
    padding-left:20px;
    }

Answer (score 2):

Please replace these css lines

```
.ActionsMenu {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    overflow-scrolling: auto;
}
#ActionsContent {
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a class selector to select an id. Either replacing `id="ActionsContent"` with `class="ActionsContent"` or replacing `.ActionsContent` with `#ActionsContent` should make sure the styles are actually applied ;)